# How to update the version of the MySQL engine in ClearDB?

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench, cleardb

By default, heroku only works with the postgreSQL database. However, there is a ClearDB plugin that allows you to use a MySQL database. The problem is that this plugin uses the old version of the MySQL 5.5.62 engine. When connecting to the server using MySQL Workbench, a warning appears

> Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (5.5.62). A connection to this database can be established but some MYSQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MYSQL. MYSQL Workbench is developed and tested for MYSQL Server version 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0

I tried to create a new database, clearly indicating the version of the engine using the command:

```
heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite --version=5.7
```

However, this did not help, the same warning still appears. How to update the version of the MySQL engine in ClearDB?

Comment: "However, this did not help, the same warning still appears. How to update the version of the MySQL engine in ClearDB?"—are you sure you're connecting to the new database, not the old one?

Comment: @Chris I'm sure I'm connecting to a new database. Before connecting, I edit setings.py

Comment: "Before connecting, I edit setings.py"—how are you doing that? Locally, then committing and pushing? Via `heroku run`? Something else?

Comment: (Also, as a side note, you shouldn't be editing any files to change your database connection information. That should come from the environment. Use something like `os.getenv()`.)

Answer (score 15):

An update. On March 26, I tried this:

```
$ heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite --name=my-db-name --version=5.7
```

As it says on Heroku DOC:

> ClearDB provisions MySQL 5.6 by default on our new G5 infrastructure, but we support MySQL 5.5, 5.6, and 5.7. If you wish to use a specific version of the aforementioned MySQL versions, simply specify the version argument to the `heroku addons:create` command

However, it does not work for their `ignite` (shared) plan. The `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` outputs:

```
innodb_version            5.5.62
protocol_version          10
slave_type_conversions    ""
version                   5.5.62-log
version_comment           MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine   x86_64
version_compile_os        Linux
```

---

#### Alternative Solution:

I used another addon called `JAWSDB`.
It works the same way that ClearDB works and you can install it the same way.
As they say in their DOC:

> JawsDB users can choose their database version at provision time by specifying a --version flag. Versions 5.7 and 8.0 are currently supported. If no version flag is supplied, the default database version will be used. The current default database version is 5.7

So, this command worked just fine:

```
$ heroku addons:create jawsdb:kitefin --name=my-db-name --version=5.7
```

The `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` outputs:

```
innodb_version            5.7.23
protocol_version          10
slave_type_conversions    ""
tls_version               TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
version                   5.7.23-log
version_comment           Source distribution
version_compile_machine   x86_64
version_compile_os        Linux
```

There is almost no difference between these two addons. You can check the features you get in each under the `Plans & Pricing` section in [ClearDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb) and [JawsDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb).

Comment: I had the same problem with ClearDB on the `Punch` plan. I could not get above MySQL 5.5, and I could not change to a region other than US. JawsDB worked so much better with MySQL 8 out of the box on the `Leopard Shared` plan

Comment: Great man you very much!! you made my day

Answer (score 2):

ClearDB [says](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#the-cleardb-dedicated-mysql-complete-tutorial-local-setup) that they offer 5.6 by default in their dedicated G5 infrastructure. I think the inference is that on shared infrastructure (what's used by `ignite`), that's not possible. Declaring a version doesn't seem to have any effect, and you're given 5.5.