# ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 30: Invalid default value for 'created_at'

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku

Deploying to Heroku and having trouble uploading an SQL export from phpMyAdmin

SQL Export Settings:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Error Message

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 30: Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

Using Step 11 from this [tutorial on scotch.io](https://scotch.io/@phalconVee/deploying-a-php-and-mysql-web-app-with-heroku)

I feel like I am having issues with different versions of MySQL.

Comment: You are probably using an old version of MySQL.  This should work in MySQL 5.6+.

Comment: what is the version you are using?

Comment: The version from phpMyAdmin says 5.0.4, I don't know what version I'm using with CLEARDB, I took the defaults when setting up.

Comment: It seems that the free version for CLEARDB is MySQL 5.5... You have to have the paid version for 5.6+

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

`created_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. <-- it is not a function so do not use `()`

Comment: The only other thing I see that is strange is that you are starting a transaction ... DDL in MySQL does not support transaction.  also when I run 
```CREATE TABLE `posts` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `body` text NOT NULL,
     `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;``` on a local mysql instance it creates succesfully

Comment: Though when I run the above inside a transaction my local mysql does not complain about it at all ... does line 30 of your script actually reference the CREATE block of code?

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your efforts.  I found out that I was stuck in an old version of MySQL because of the heroku addon I was using called CLEARDB.  I switched to JAWSDB with SQL v5.7 and used MySQL workbench to import the sql file and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my version of CLEARDB was 5.5 and I could not get a newer version under a free account.  Switched to JAWSDB and I am using a free account(I think) with 5.7

[How to update the version of the MySQL engine in ClearDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253354/how-to-update-the-version-of-the-mysql-engine-in-cleardb)